# laravel-mix running npm run dev throw "This dependency was not found"

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I've set up my `webpack.mix.js` as it follow:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/pace.js', 'public/js/load.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I checked if `pace.js` is in the folder `resources/assets/js` and it is.
Then run `npm run dev` and I get this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                          14:37:37

This dependency was not found:

* pace in ./resources/assets/js/pace.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save pace
            Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
       /js/app.js   1.26 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
      /js/load.js   30.8 kB       1  [emitted]         /js/load
mix-manifest.json  64 bytes          [emitted]         

npm ERR! Darwin 16.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v7.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

---

#### Edit 1

I just discovered that actually `npm run dev` is throwing the error but also compiling. So if I go to `public/js/` I can see `load.js` and everything seems to be correct inside.
This is making me more confused.

npm version is 4.1.2 and node version is 7.6.0

Comment: The error is explicit you have to install pace with: `npm install --save pace`

Comment: @dparoli well it happens with every file I put there, not only dependencies for example if I use `.js('resources/assets/js/whatever.js', 'public/js/load.js')` give the same error with `* whatever in ./resources/assets/js/whatever.js`.

Comment: ok, sorry @Angus for me your code is working, I have node 6.10.1 and npm 3.10.10 if this helps

Comment: @dparoli why sorry? Thanks for your help, but I can't figure out how to solve and why this is happening. To you is it working also with custom js files ?

Comment: @dparoli ok I found it. The error was inside `pace.js` when importing with `import pace from `./pace.js`. I Think I was quite confused. Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: nice to know you solved, thinks that happens ;)